# "Valums" file uploader and method POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

My problem is that the file-uploader `http://valums.com/ajax-upload/` adds params to the URL instead of passing them by POST.

For example:

```
action:'/upload.php'
params : { x1:'x1'}
```

... will submit as the URL:

> /upload.php?x1=x1

(GET), but I need to pass additional params by POST. Is this possible?

Comment: I had a quick look at the source and I think that the library only supports parameters as query string. It shouldn't be too difficult to implement the functionality you want though. Maybe a fork already does what you want…

Comment: is it cross-domain ajax?

Comment: i guess it will be hard for me to make changes, also it's not cross-domain

Comment: @kusanagi the ajax-upload supports POST, but i am assuming you are using the file-uploader this link might help you https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/issues#issue/57

Comment: why do you need to pass the parameter by POST?

Comment: one thing to note, that plugin uses post with iframes for some IE versions, for FF and chrome it'll use the XHR.  The params object should work, not sure about size limits though.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using an [old version](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) of ajax-upload.
I found [this new one](http://valums.com/files/2009/ajax-upload/demo-jquery.htm).

Here's an example of it working OK with a `data` attribute properly converted to hidden input fields:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/XkCP5/

```
var button = $('#button1'), interval;
new AjaxUpload(button,{
    //action: 'upload-test.php', // I disabled uploads in this example for security reasons
    action: 'upload.htm', 
--> data: {field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'}, <--
    ...
```

I stopped the submission of the file and got this automatically created form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="display: none;" action="upload.htm" target="ValumsAjaxUpload0">
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="value1">
    <input type="hidden" name="field2" value="value2">
    <input type="file" name="myfile" style="position: absolute; margin: -5px 0pt 0pt -175px; padding: 0pt; width: 220px; height: 30px; font-size: 14px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer; display: block; z-index: 2147483583; top: 48px; left: 147px;">
</form>
```

Comment: this is actually an older version from 2009 and has no progressbar